# Loop pages and crawler excel file path using rvest

Tags: r, web-crawler, rvest, rcrawler

For the entries from [this link](http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c100121/common_list.shtml), I need to click each entry, then crawler url of excel file's path in the left bottom part of page:

[image]

How could I achieve that using web scrapy packages in R such as `rvest`, etc.? Sincere thanks at advance.

```
library(rvest)

# Start by reading a HTML page with read_html():
common_list <- read_html("http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c100121/common_list.shtml")
common_list %>%
  # extract paragraphs
  rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
  # extract text
  rvest::html_text() -> webtxt
# inspect
head(webtxt)
```

First, my question is how could I correctly set `html_nodes` to get url of each web page?

[image]

**Update:**

```
> driver
$client
[1] "No sessionInfo. Client browser is mostly likely not opened."

$server
PROCESS 'file105483d2b3a.bat', running, pid 37512.
> remDr
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4567

$browserName
[1] "chrome"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()
```

When I run `remDr$navigate(url)`:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Comment: Can't see any excel file when clicked on a entry, maybe it is location specific.

Comment: Please check in this link: http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1758587/content.shtml, others are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rvest` to get the links,

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(RSelenium)

link <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%  
  html_nodes('.mt10')

link <- link[[2]] %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>% paste0('http://www.csrc.gov.cn', .)

 [1] "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1758587/content.shtml"                         
 [2] "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1714636/content.shtml"                         
 [3] "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1664367/content.shtml"                         
 [4] "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1657437/content.shtml"                         
 [5] "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1657426/content.shtml"
```

We can use `RSelenium` to loop over the links and download excel files.
It took me over a minute to completely load a single webpage. I will demonstrate hetre using a single link.

```
url <- "http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc/c101921/c1758587/content.shtml"
# launch the browser
driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]

# click on the excel file path
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="files"]/a')$clickElement()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, please note I don't need to download excel files, loop the pages and store them as dataframe with column names: `excel_filename`, `url` will be perfect.

Comment: @NadPat to add up to your answer, there is a POST API to be used. You can send a POST request to `http://www.csrc.gov.cn/getManuscriptData`. The body of the POST request takes a form-encoded string with two arguments `mId` and `status`. `status` is always 4; `mId` is the character sequence in "cxxxxxxx", 1758587 in this case. It returns a json string.

Comment: Thanks for post this insightful comment @ekoam, do you mind share your solutions? I literally know nothing regarding R crawler.

Comment: @ahbon This is already a good (and robust) solution to your problem. If you don't really understand how to send a POST request, then you should probably not do it since it is a bit technical. If you understand POST requests well enough, you should know that the comment above has provided enough information for you to work with. In R, you can send a POST request using `httr::POST`. The documentation is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.2/topics/POST).

Comment: OK, I'll look in detail this solution, thanks for sharing your ideas and solutions.

Comment: I tested, it raises an error: `Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`.